# excel - find same names but with different addresses

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Ok I've been racking my brain about this but can't come up with a clean way of getting the data I need.

I have a large list of customer information. I am interested in finding out where customers have bought different items, the layout of my cells is like:

> Customer Name, Customer Address, Product
>
> Joe Bloggs, 123 The Avenue, Apples
>
> Joe Bloggs, 123 The Avenue, Apples
>
> Jim Smith, 456 The Road, Oranges
>
> Jim Smith, 456 The Road, Apples

So in this case, I'm not interested in Joe Bloggs as he bought Apples both times. I'm interested in Jim as he bought Oranges AND Apples. Is there a helper column I could use to help me filter this data out? So, counting if the customer name and address appears more than once and if the products are different? Thanks.

Comment: Are you OK with VBA macros or do you only want Excel worksheet functions?

Comment: Fine with either thanks

Comment: thanks pnuts, apols the commas in my layout above should actually represent different columns of data as opposed to one cell per row in comma delimited.

Comment: Try `=COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,B2,C:C,C2)` in row 2 and drag down in a helper column and filtering only on the `1` (unique rows, if that is what you are looking for).

Comment: You can put everything in a pivot-table and then screen out the stuff you want to look at. Sometimes easier to eyeball it like that than jump through hoops with convoluted formulae

Comment: cool thanks both, both approaches can get me what i need, so great stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best way to do this is creating a pivot tabel wich is based on the customer and the product

then sort on amount of products

Succes 
Toontje